# Whenever I try to log in, I receive "405: Method not allowed for this URL" What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I already searched through here and found some very similar issues, but with me being new to Python, I found it very difficult to debug this code.

I am making a simple blog app, with a database for a login.
It runs perfectly on the IDE, but when I attempt to log in, I receive a 405 error and that the 'Method is not allowed.'

What did I get wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, \
flash, redirect, url_for, g
import sqlite3


SECRET_KEY = 'abc12345678910111213'
# configuration
DATABASE = 'blog.db'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'admin'

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    status_code = 200
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME'] or \
            request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
        error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please Try again!'
    status_code = 401
else:
    session['logged_in'] = True
    return redirect(url_for('main'))
return render_template('login.html', error=error), status_code

@app.route('/main')
def main():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Welcome, Friends!</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
         <div class="flash">{{ message }}</div>
     {% endfor %}
     {% if error %}
         <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
     {% endif %}
     <!--inheritance-->
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
     <!--end inheritance-->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your indentation in login() is incorrect. What does your template look like. I bet your problem comes from the `main` endpoint not allowing a `POST` request. Try `@app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST']`

Comment: @MrLeeh You were correct, I did not specify the get and post methods. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `POST` method in your allowed methods of the `main` endpoint:

```
@app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    # ...
    pass
```